# Add A Page Link / Anchor To A Rails Resource in routes.rb

Tags: ruby, routes, ruby-on-rails-5

In my `routes.rb` I have a route:

```
resources :chat-messages
```

Any time a visitor hits `/chat-messages` I would like the page to load a view with the following url: `/chat-messages#example`. This will scroll the page to a div with the id of `example`.

*Is there any way to handle this purely within `routes.rb`*, so that a link that uses `chat_messages_path` will still render the url including the anchor?

Answer (score -1):

To load on same page, provide id where you have click link like button

`<a class="btn btn-primary" href="#example"> example</a>`

```
<div id="example">
</div>
```

No need to make changes in routes

and apply the same id to the div which you want to show

or 
You can try like this will work to open the in new page

```
 <%= link_to chat_messages_path(anchor: "example"), method: :get do %>
```

Comment: Like I say in the question in italics: Is there any way to handle this purely within routes.rb? Doing it with a link is trivial.